# In React, how do I display a page that uses data from a specific item from a database

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my database, I have multiple exercises and I display all of them in the main page. I want to be able to click the "View Exercise" button to see information about that exercise itself.

App.js route code:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={MainPage} exact />
          <Route path="/exercises/:name" component={Exercise} exact/>
          <Route component={Error} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
  );
};
```

Code component that should show a specific exercise:

```
import React from "react";

function Exercise(props) {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hi {props.name} !</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Exercise;
```

How I display the list of exercises:

```
function Exercises() {
  const [exercise, setExercise] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      const getAPI = async () => {
          const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/');
          const data = await response.json();

          try {
              console.log(data);
              setExercise(data);
          } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
          }
      };
      getAPI();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 id="exercises">List of Exercises</h2>
      <Row>
        {exercise.map((data) => (
          <ExerciseCard
            key = {data._id}
            name = {data.name}
            img = {data.image}
          />
        ))}
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Exercises;
```

The button link:

```
<Link to= {{
  pathname: `/exercises/${props.name}`
  }}
>
```

Comment: Are you ***just*** trying to display the exercise name in the header in `Exercise` component? Or do you want the entire `data`/`exercise` object? If you just need the `name` route parameter then use [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) to access it in the route's component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're trying to pass an exercise name to the `Exercise` component via URL query parameter.

In this case you could use `useParams` hook from `react-router`. So the component becomes:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";

function Exercise(props) {
  const { name } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hi {name} !</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Exercise;
```

And the name for the `name` parameter is set in route declaration `<Route path="/exercises/:name" component={Exercise} exact/>`

If you're going to display more data than a name, you could consider doing an API call inside `useEffect` hook to get the details.